# Get the json received via http call in an array - Swift iOS

Tags: arrays, json, swift, http

I am having the following function to get an external json.

```
func httpGet(request: NSURLRequest!, callback: (String, String?) -> Void) {

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {

        } else {
            let result = NSString(data: data!, encoding:
                NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
            callback(result as String, nil)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

I invoke the function with the below code.

```
httpGet(request){       
  (data, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print(data)
            }
        }
```

I am getting a json return as below. Now I want it in an array.

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  }]
```

But for some reasons all function I found online throws some error. What will be the best way to do this?

Comment: array of what? a custom class ?!

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
func example(data:NSData){
    do{
        if let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers]) as? [NSDictionary]{
            for json in jsonArray{
                // takes all the values
                let userId = json.objectForKey("userId") as? Int
                ......
            }
        }
    }catch{
        //handles the error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Paste your JSON to http://www.json4swift.com

2 - Move the generated classes to your Xcode project

3 - In your existing code, perform the following:

```
 httpGet(request){
            (data, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                do{
                    if let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers]) as? [NSDictionary]{

                        //Here's your array mapped as models
                        let modelsArray = YourModelClassGenerated.modelsFromDictionaryArray(jsonArray)

                    }
                }catch{
                    //handles the error
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you.